# Animating scroll view height - content suddenly jumps up prior to animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview

Here are some screenshots of what's happening.

The green background is a view in the scrollview (i.e. marks the "content size" and "content offset").

The orange is the scroll view frame.

**The keyboard is up... the scroll view has scrolled the content nicely.**

[image]

**Now I click off the text field and the keyboard starts to hide**

[image]

Although the scroll view (orange) seems to be the right height, the content has now jumped up about 100px (green).

I have no idea what's causing this - whether its an ios bug or what (it happens on my device as well).

This is the code which resizes the view based on when the keyboard gets shown/hidden.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif {
    [self.mainScrollView setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
    // get the scroll view frame size
    CGRect frame = [self.mainScrollView frame];
    frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height-216;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"scrollViewAnimations" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [self.mainScrollView setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // add tap gesture recognizer
    _tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_dismissKeyboard:)];
    [_tap setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_tap];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notif {
    CGRect frame = [self.mainScrollView frame];
    frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"scrollViewAnimations" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [self.mainScrollView setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:_tap];
}
```

Any help or guidance would be great, thank you! Why is it doing this? Is it a bug - is it something buried in my code somewhere? I can't find it if it is. Is this an error with the way I'm doing my view animations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my solution to a similar problem in RubyMotion:

```
def keyboardWillShow(notification)
  point = searchBar.convertPoint(searchBar.frame.origin, toView:tableView)
  tableView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
end

def keyboardWillHide(notification)
  info = notification.userInfo
  duration = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey)

  UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context:nil)
  UIView.setAnimationDuration(duration)
  tableView.setContentOffset([0,0], animated: false)
  UIView.commitAnimations
end
```

The idea here being you don't really want to mutate the frame you instead want to adjust the content offset of the UIScrollView

Comment: That's interesting. I might be able to work something out like this, instead of how I'm doing it. :) I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: +1 for setting the duration of the animation to the duration of the keyboard animation.

Comment: Ok, I've taken a bit of what you're doing. I've kept my "scroll the view up" code. Then on the hiding of the keyboard I'm setting the content height to be `+= 216`, setting the scrollview frame to the height of the view (no animation) and then animating the content offset to `{0,0}`.